# Difference between double and DOUBLE in C++

Tags: c++, numbers

I wondered what's the difference between `double` and `DOUBLE` (from `#include <Windows>`) in C++. There's a lot of question about it in Java, but that's a totally different language.

Is `DOUBLE` just a Windows wrapper class for `double`, or something else?
Do they have different advantages?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Wouter: Amazingly, they forgot `DOUBLE` on that page.

Comment: Haha, didn't even check it, seems like they did! :)

Comment: @Cameron: Just noticed that too, but it just lists all data types, doesn't explain the difference,...

Comment: OP could have figured this out himself by clicking "Go to definition"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`double` is a C++ keyword while `DOUBLE` is implementation defined typedef.

For example if I will include `<Windows.h>` in a project in MS VC++ then the IDE shows that `DOUBLE` is defined in `WTypesbase.h` like:

```
typedef double DOUBLE;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is there any difference between the two, or just the typedef from MS?

Comment: @Blitz Rakete  You can yourself look the definition of DOUBLE in the mentioned by you header. What is the problem? If DOUBLE is defined like typedef double DOUBLE; then they are the same.